# Why do i get: "Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'TRAINING1.Node<int>' " error?

Tags: c#, list, class, stack

this is a function that is supposed to take a list and reverse it. i do not know why i get this error.

```
    public static void What(List<int> lst)
    {
        Stack<int> st1 = new Stack<int>();
        while (!lst.IsEmpty())
        {
            **st1.Push(lst.Remove(lst.GetFirst().GetInfo());**
        }
        Node<int> pos = lst.GetFirst();
        while (!st1.IsEmpty())
        {
            pos = lst.Insert(pos, st1.Pop());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does .GetInfo() return?

Comment: What are methods: GetFirst() and .GetInfo() ? - I assume they don't return an int?

Comment: You are passing pos as the first argument to the lst.Insert method.  That argument should be an int not a Node<int> which is what pos is.

Answer (score 2):

`st1` is a `Stack<int>`, which means that it is a strongly-typed stack of ints. You cannot add `Node<int>`   to this list, if the is no implicit convertion from `Node<int>` to `int`. Anyway, try to use next code as an example of working with stack:

```
public static void Reverse(List<int> lst)
{
   Stack<int> st1 = new Stack<int>();
   while (lst.Count != 0)
   {
        var item = lst[0];
        lst.RemoveAt(0);
        st1.Push(item);
   }
   while (st1.Count != 0)
   {
       lst.Add(st1.Pop());
   }
}
```

This is not an efficient solution and has a huge amount of drawbacks. I just want to illustrate correct reversing method using stack as close as possible to your case.

You can make method `Reverse` generic, but the are already implemented behavior in Linq.

Consider using [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) Linq method. If you want just to reverse `List<int>`, use `myList.Reverse().ToList()`. It will return the same `List<int>` but in reversed order.

Comment: + 1 for the Reverse Linq method

Comment: No need for the first loop. `Stack<int> st1 = new Stack<int>(lst); lst.Clear();` is enough

Comment: @I4V yes, thank you, I know. I wanted to make correct behavior close to the OPs question. there is also no need to specify `int`. Just use `new Stack<T>(lst); lst.Clear();` and make `Reverse<T> (List<T> lst)`

Comment: thank you all for commenting :)  GetInfo() is supposed to return the info in the node - an int. Why doesnt it work this way? how do i make the computer recognize the int of the node and use st1.Push(...) on it?(in the line of the error: **st1.Push(lst.Remove(lst.GetFirst().GetInfo());** )